# Quickblox Chat Application,Android

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using *Quickblox Api* for building chat Application,successfully integrated in my app,but When I am Login to Chat Application for first Time my session token also generated,calls all relevant api,except this url  POST https://api.quickblox.com/chat/Dialog.json?name=shailesh&type=3&occupants_ids=2142362,  I am not getting response back only for first time
but when I check isLoggedIn()i.e (For Second Time) the same url give me success.

Please help me,
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are passing the Jabber ID correctly?

Checkout:http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Connect_QuickBlox_to_your_application

Remember:

- standard login+password authentication: use same password
- Facebook/Twitter authentication: use session token as password

here's what quickblox says:

```
QBUser user = new QBUser();
user.setId(id);  //id is int
try {
    user.setPassword(BaseService.getBaseService().getToken());
}catch(BaseServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
    // means you have not created a session before 
}
```